# How can I make a counter?

Tags: iphone, delay, counter

How can I make a counter from 0 to 10 choosing the delay?

Comment: What language???  Please give more info, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `NSTimer`,

Check the below code as reference.

```
- (void) startCounter {
     counterCount = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:0.09f target:self selector:@selector(showElapsedTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

`showElapsedTime` will be called after delay, you provide.

```
-(void) showElapsedTime: (NSTimer *) timer {
    counterCount++;
    if(counterCount == 10)
    {
      [timer invalidate];
    }

// Write your code here 
}
```

Comment: You just need to invalidate the timer at some point, which the above code does not illustrate. Edit: The code above now works, but a static counter makes more sense in this context than an ivar.

Answer (score 1):

Create an NSTimer:

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds 
                                     target:(id)target 
                                   selector:(SEL)aSelector 
                                   userInfo:(id)userInfo 
                                    repeats:(BOOL)repeats;
```

Yours would probably look like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                  target:self
                                selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                userInfo:nil
                                 repeats:YES];
```

In the method that is invoked, increment a counter, and check to see if you've hit your count to stop the timer:

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
     static int counter = 0;

     // Do Something

     counter++;
     if(counter == 10)
          [timer invalidate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `[performSelector: withObject: afterDelay]` of the NSObject class is normally used for timed operations.